# Difference in calling printf from sh and bash

Tags: bash, sh, quoting

I am having trouble understanding the difference between the output of the two scripts below and would like someone to explain why there's a difference.

Script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
f() {
    x=$(printf "%q" "$1")
    echo "x = $x"
}
f 'he\llo'
```

This outputs: `x = he\\llo`

Script 2:

```
#!/bin/sh
f() {
    x=$(printf "%q" "$1")
    echo "x = $x"
}
f 'he\llo'
```

This outputs: `x = he\llo`

Probably, sh doesn't have a built-in printf and is using /usr/bin/printf while bash does have a built-in printf. But I don't get the significance of how this makes the output different.

Comment: `printf %q` is explicitly a bash extension, not present in POSIX printf

Comment: ...also, in bash, `x=$(printf "%q" "$1")` is unnecessarily inefficient (and also has the probably-undesired behavior of trimming trailing newlines on account of the command substitution). Use `printf -v x '%q' "$1"` to avoid the subshell overhead and store results precisely.

Comment: What shell is your `sh`? I don't see that with bash-as-sh (bash 3.2.25) here. And to second what @CharlesDuffy said trying to use `%q` with `/usr/bin/printf` gets `/usr/bin/printf: %q: invalid conversion specification` as output.

Answer (score 2):

`printf %q` is explicitly a bash extension, not present in POSIX printf.

Thus, the behavior you get from any implementation *other than that provided by bash* is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is `echo` behaving like `echo -e` in whatever shell you have as `sh`.

```
$ cat test.sh
f() {
    x="$(printf "%q" "$1")"
    declare -p x
    echo "echo: x = $x"
    echo -e "echo -e: x = $x"
    printf 'printf: x = %s\n' "$x"
}
f 'he\llo'

$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ /bin/bash test.sh
declare -- x="he\\\\llo"
echo: x = he\\llo
echo -e: x = he\llo
printf: x = he\\llo

$ /bin/sh test.sh
declare -- x="he\\\\llo"
echo: x = he\\llo
echo -e: x = he\llo
printf: x = he\\llo
```